# Unable to load echart on dynamically created element

Tags: pie-chart, echarts, apache-echarts

We are facing a blank chart while initializing echart on a dynamically created element.

We had tried using the below snippet.

```
let chartDom = document.createElement("div");
chartDom.style.height = "350px";
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom, null, {
    renderer: 'canvas',
});
```

Comment: Have you added the new div to the DOM? There's no method call like [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) in your code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.init):

> dom - Instance container, usually is a DIV element with height **and width** defined.

So I would suggest defining the width of the div element.